# Redux.createStore() at module level throws "TypeError ... is not a function"

Tags: redux, react-redux

If I call Redux.createStore() from the module-level of my app, it will cause the engine to throw

```
index.jsx?4657:77 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _redux.createStore)(...) is not a function
```

By trial and error I found that if I call it within a function, all is well.  For example:

```
(function() {
   const store = createStore(reducer)
   ...
)()
```

Can anyone explain why this is so?  In fact, the examples in http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html call createStore() at the module level.  Is this a hidden gotcha that other devs need to know about or is could this be the result of some funkiness in my webpack config or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createStore() has been depreciated now in Redux-toolkit, better checkout for configureStore().